# Playing multiple videos at once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming

I'm using http handler to retrieve video from database
this is my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetAttachmentConnectionString());
string vidId = context.Request.QueryString["VidID"];
con.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select FileData from Attachment where AttachmentId = 1002", con);

SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
context.Response.Buffer = true;
context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);

con.Close();
context.Response.End();
```

And I'm using a Video tag on the client page.
The issue is that everything works fine if there is only one video playing on the page. If I'm retrieving more than one, it shows a black box with controls and time 0:0

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

USE REPEATER FOR THIS TO VIEW MULTIPLE VIDEO FROM DATABASE